# Rollback all transactions if one transaction throws error in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

I'm new to dynamoDB and currently trying to develop a module which writes into the dynamoDB database using transactWrite.
Transactions are only allowed for a batch of 25 items but I want to add 500 items in the database in a All-or-none basis.
I'm using transactWrite in loop with batches of 25 each. I am able to stop the transactions at the point where I get an error but not able to rollback the transactions that have already committed.
Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Hey man, any update about this? I'm in the same situation